# Google maps api v2 on avd

Tags: android, google-maps

I have some basic app that show map to user
I have set almost everything like in this tutorial  http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ and it worked for one time, then i pushed it to the repository, and after that i recive such error and all i can see is net with zoom out in button without map. So what is wrong ?

```
 Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@b347fa50
 D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
 D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
 D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(23): 62|147
 D/REQUEST﹕ Close
 D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@b31bd690 not retrying
```

Comment: Double check package names and API keys.

Comment: i have copied packed name exactly from my project so there is no chance  that is the reason as i said it worked for one time, i have even made a screen...

Comment: You switched systems, i.e. reinstalled your IDE?

Comment: i have changed folder structure of my app From Some folder ->App folder -> all app files now its Some folder -> all app files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know the reason but creating new api key solved my problem